# FB Code // Images stacked vertically, how to place horizontally

Tags: html, css, facebook, api

using the script code below, this returns the images from facebook vertically. ive removed all traces of breaks and lines, and would assume that this would show the images one after another horizontally, but just shows them in a vertical stack...

blatantly obvious that im a "dirty copy and paster" but hey, we all gotta start somewhere!

```
{
var divContainer = document.createElement("div");
divContainer.innerHTML="%img src='http://graph.facebook.com/"+data[friendIndex].id+"/picture'%%/img%";
divTarget.appendChild(divContainer);
}
```

image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DS3N4.png

also, massive apologies, but the < > tags around the img in the code makes the code disappear so ive replaced them with %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more an HTML/CSS issue than a Facebook/Graph API issue. `div`'s are going to be rendered vertically. Try using a `<span>` tag instead:

```
var spanContainer = document.createElement("span");
spanContainer.innerHTML = "<src='http://graph.facebook.com/"+data[friendIndex].id+"/picture' />";
divTarget.appendChild(spanContainer);
```

Comment: var spanContainer = document.createElement("span");
spanContainer.innerHTML="<img src='http://graph.facebook.com/"+data[friendIndex].id+"/picture'></img>";
divTarget.appendChild(spanContainer);

is the code;

<div>
<h1>Friends Images</h1>
<span id="friends-list-container"></span>
</div>

is the entry code?

Comment: @kelvinmead I'm not sure I understand what you're asking...the code above is the javascript, which will generate HTML that's something like <span><img src='...' /></span> when inserted into the DOM with the `appendChild` call.

Comment: boom... lost!

using the example on http://www.permadi.com/blog/2010/11/facebook-graph-api-showing-list-of-friends/

i copied the code from http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/facebook-graph-api-friens-selector/with-picture.html source, 

embedded into my site and i get a perfect copy of the site (with my styling as you'd expect)

as you said use <span>, where i saw <div> around the image section of the page, i changed it to <span>

you can see this at line 387 at http://kelvinmaed.com/datatable.html :)

im not gonna lie, i have no idea what im doing, im just trying!

Comment: Oh, I see...I think. So no, you still want the friends-list-container to be a `div`, as it was originally. Just the elements you append to it should be `span`s

Comment: so do a <div><span id=container>containerbit</span></div>

Comment: Well, that part isn't so important; as long as your `getElementById("friends-list-container")` gets a valid element, here div/span doesn't matter. Looking at the code you linked to though, your problem could be in the `<!-- ... -->` (HTML comment markers) you used to comment out your previous code; change those to `/* ... */` (javascript comment markers).

Comment: thanks! working perfectly! not so much in the <!-- but in the accuracy of my coding! went through it all again and did it right! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed correct with the previous HTML / CSS comment. To be clear about this, the DIV tag has by default a display attribute of block and the SPAN tag defaults to inline. Inline-block could also be used, but the best way to tackle the issue would be to give your divContainer a class name and define that class in your CSS declarations with the desired inline value for the display attribute.